Moveit control for a robot in Gazebo
I have mounted a Gen3 robotic arm on a clearpath Husky mobile robot in Gazebo Fortress and I have established a Gazebo-ROS bridge using ROS2 humble. Everything is working well and I can command both the Gen3 arm and the Husky robot with ros2 topics, however I am facing issues when I try to command the arm using Moveit2.
To elaborate, when I launch the simulation, the controller manager starts all the needed controllers to command both the arm and the mobile robot and everything is inside one namespace: “a200_0000”. Afterward I try to launch the Moveit’s demo.launch.py file from the moveit package that I created using  the setup assistant. The demo.launch.py is launched under the same namespace “a200_0000” using the following code:
from launch import LaunchDescription 
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import PushRosNamespace
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
import os

def generate_launch_description():
# Define the path to your demo.launch.py file
demo_launch_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('clearpath_moveit_config'), 'launch', 'demo.launch.py')

# Wrap the demo launch in a namespace using PushRosNamespace
return LaunchDescription([
# Apply the namespace to all nodes within the group
PushRosNamespace('a200_0000'),
# Include the demo launch file inside the namespace
IncludeLaunchDescription(
PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(demo_launch_file),
),
])

Howerver, once Moveit is started and Rviz appears, my ros2_control node dies and no planner gets loaded in rviz.

Here`s the ros2_controllers.yaml file in the moveit package:
# This config file is used by ros2_control
controller_manager:
ros__parameters:
update_rate: 100 # Hz

arm_0_joint_trajectory_controller:
type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

joint_state_broadcaster:
type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

arm_0_joint_trajectory_controller:
ros__parameters:
joints:
- arm_0_joint_1
- arm_0_joint_2
- arm_0_joint_3
- arm_0_joint_4
- arm_0_joint_5
- arm_0_joint_6
- arm_0_joint_7
command_interfaces:
- position
state_interfaces:
- position
- velocity

And here`s the moveit_controllers.yaml file:
# MoveIt uses this configuration for controller management
moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager

moveit_simple_controller_manager:
controller_names:
- arm_0_joint_trajectory_controller

arm_0_joint_trajectory_controller:
type: FollowJointTrajectory
action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
default: True
joints:
- arm_0_joint_1
- arm_0_joint_2
- arm_0_joint_3
- arm_0_joint_4
- arm_0_joint_5
- arm_0_joint_6
- arm_0_joint_7

Here are my terminal logs:
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [7236]
[INFO] [move_group-2]: process started with pid [7238]
[INFO] [rviz2-3]: process started with pid [7240]
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-4]: process started with pid [7242]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [7244]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [7246]
[rviz2-3] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[ros2_control_node-4] [WARN] [1725636335.390405190] [a200_0000.controller_manager]: 'update_rate' parameter not set, using default value.
[ros2_control_node-4] [WARN] [1725636335.391015709] [a200_0000.controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
[ros2_control_node-4] [INFO] [1725636335.391448817] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'a200_hardware' 
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394579619] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_0_base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394673863] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_0_bracelet_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394678844] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_0_end_effector_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394682321] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_0_forearm_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394685447] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_0_half_arm_1_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394688582] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_0_half_arm_2_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394691574] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_0_shoulder_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394694652] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_0_spherical_wrist_1_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394697708] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment arm_0_spherical_wrist_2_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394700595] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394703644] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394706629] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment default_mount
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394709638] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_bumper_base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394712638] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_bumper_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394715638] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_bumper_mount
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394718594] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394721599] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment front_right_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394724561] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment inertial_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394727452] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment rear_bumper_mount
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394730321] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment rear_left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394733285] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment rear_right_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394736180] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment top_chassis_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1725636335.394739027] [a200_0000.robot_state_publisher]: got segment user_bay_cover_link
[ros2_control_node-4] [INFO] [1725636335.400354688] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'a200_hardware' 
[ros2_control_node-4] [INFO] [1725636335.400635850] [A200Hardware]: Name: a200_hardware
[ros2_control_node-4] [INFO] [1725636335.400647022] [A200Hardware]: Number of Joints 4
[ros2_control_node-4] [INFO] [1725636335.454678348] [A200Hardware]: Port: /dev/clearpath/prolific
[ros2_control_node-4] Unable to open /dev/clearpath/prolific
EXCEPTION: TransportException 2: Failed to open serial port
[ros2_control_node-4] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'clearpath::TransportException*'
[ros2_control_node-4] Stack trace (most recent call last):
[ros2_control_node-4] #21   Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636335.488556582] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.042097 seconds
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636335.490501225] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'a200-0000'...
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636335.490624937] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[ros2_control_node-4] #20   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x60a03c734d84, in 
[ros2_control_node-4] #19   Source "../csu/libc-start.c", line 392, in __libc_start_main_impl [0x7c7821a29e3f]
[ros2_control_node-4] #18   Source "../sysdeps/nptl/libc_start_call_main.h", line 58, in __libc_start_call_main [0x7c7821a29d8f]
[ros2_control_node-4] #17   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node", at 0x60a03c73489e, in 
[ros2_control_node-4] #16   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7c78223bde79, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::ControllerManager(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Executor>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rclcpp::NodeOptions const&)
[ros2_control_node-4] #15   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libcontroller_manager.so", at 0x7c78223b96bf, in controller_manager::ControllerManager::init_resource_manager(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
[ros2_control_node-4] #14   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7c7821da6d9d, in hardware_interface::ResourceManager::load_urdf(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool, bool)
[ros2_control_node-4] #13   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7c7821da5e7b, in 
[ros2_control_node-4] #12   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7c7821dcdcaa, in 
[ros2_control_node-4] #11   Object "/opt/ros/humble/lib/libhardware_interface.so", at 0x7c7821dcc1db, in hardware_interface::System::initialize(hardware_interface::HardwareInfo const&)
[ros2_control_node-4] #10   Object "/home/aalmrad/demos/clearpath_kinova/clearpath_ws/build/clearpath_platform/liba200_hardware.so", at 0x7c781996d824, in clearpath_platform::A200Hardware::on_init(hardware_interface::HardwareInfo const&)
[ros2_control_node-4] #9    Object "/home/aalmrad/demos/clearpath_kinova/clearpath_ws/build/clearpath_platform/liba200_hardware.so", at 0x7c78199c9da8, in horizon_legacy::connect(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
[ros2_control_node-4] #8    Object "/home/aalmrad/demos/clearpath_kinova/clearpath_ws/build/clearpath_platform/liba200_hardware.so", at 0x7c78199c9d43, in horizon_legacy::reconnect()
[ros2_control_node-4] #7    Object "/home/aalmrad/demos/clearpath_kinova/clearpath_ws/build/clearpath_platform/liba200_hardware.so", at 0x7c78199dc0a0, in clearpath::Transport::configure(char const*, int)
[ros2_control_node-4] #6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.32", at 0x7c7821eb7067, in __cxa_throw
[ros2_control_node-4] #5    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.32", at 0x7c7821eb6e06, in std::terminate()
[ros2_control_node-4] #4    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.32", at 0x7c7821eb6d9b, in 
[ros2_control_node-4] #3    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.32", at 0x7c7821ea4f25, in 
[ros2_control_node-4] #2    Source "./stdlib/abort.c", line 79, in abort [0x7c7821a287f2]
[ros2_control_node-4] #1    Source "../sysdeps/posix/raise.c", line 26, in raise [0x7c7821a42475]
[ros2_control_node-4] #0  | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 89, in __pthread_kill_internal
[ros2_control_node-4]     | Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 78, in __pthread_kill_implementation
[ros2_control_node-4]       Source "./nptl/pthread_kill.c", line 44, in __pthread_kill [0x7c7821a969fc]
[ros2_control_node-4] Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 7242 1001)
[move_group-2] [WARN] [1725636335.651438147] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Link user_bay_cover_link has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[move_group-2] [WARN] [1725636335.651482701] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Link front_bumper_link has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[move_group-2] [WARN] [1725636335.651519204] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Link top_chassis_link has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[move_group-2] [WARN] [1725636335.652106441] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Could not identify parent group for end-effector 'end_effector'
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636335.928839660] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636335.929348814] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636335.978280839] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.121256255] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.121956926] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.123340125] [moveit_ros.current_state_monitor]: Listening to joint states on topic 'joint_states'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.124038446] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/a200_0000/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.124055590] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.124548522] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/a200_0000/planning_scene'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.124564861] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.124949044] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'collision_object'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.125354118] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to 'planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[move_group-2] [WARN] [1725636336.125786362] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-2] [ERROR] [1725636336.125801163] [moveit.ros.occupancy_map_monitor.middleware_handle]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[spawner-6] [WARN] [1725636336.209181303] [a200_0000.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller already loaded, skipping load_controller
[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1725636336.212419116] [a200_0000.spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Failed to configure controller
[rviz2-3] Warning: class_loader.impl: SEVERE WARNING!!! A namespace collision has occurred with plugin factory for class rviz_default_plugins::displays::InteractiveMarkerDisplay. New factory will OVERWRITE existing one. This situation occurs when libraries containing plugins are directly linked against an executable (the one running right now generating this message). Please separate plugins out into their own library or just don't link against the library and use either class_loader::ClassLoader/MultiLibraryClassLoader to open.
[rviz2-3]          at line 253 in /opt/ros/humble/include/class_loader/class_loader/class_loader_core.hpp
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.351116051] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'ompl'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.374004968] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377714127] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377752944] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377758045] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'ompl.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377779302] [moveit_ros.fix_workspace_bounds]: Param 'ompl.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377795794] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377803098] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377813802] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377819236] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.jiggle_fraction' was not set. Using default value: 0.020000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377909917] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'ompl.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377923513] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377928394] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377931549] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377934082] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377936654] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.377940438] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.386090972] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'pilz_industrial_motion_planner'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.390019888] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner.joint_limits_aggregator]: Reading limits from namespace robot_description_planning
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.402220133] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Available plugins: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP 
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.402248078] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderCIRC
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.405227385] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [CIRC]
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.405248953] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderLIN
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.406732328] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [LIN]
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.406787039] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: About to load: pilz_industrial_motion_planner/PlanningContextLoaderPTP
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.409067109] [moveit.pilz_industrial_motion_planner]: Registered Algorithm [PTP]
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.409107367] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'Pilz Industrial Motion Planner'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.412701556] [moveit.ros_planning_interface.moveit_cpp]: Loading planning pipeline 'chomp'
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 7246, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_state_broadcaster --ros-args -r __ns:=/a200_0000'].
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.418515649] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning interface 'CHOMP'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419392218] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.path_tolerance' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419402184] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.resample_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.100000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419405081] [moveit_ros.add_time_optimal_parameterization]: Param 'chomp.min_angle_change' was not set. Using default value: 0.001000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419419422] [moveit_ros.fix_workspace_bounds]: Param 'chomp.default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10.000000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419429666] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.100000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419433116] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_bounds]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419440718] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.500000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419443812] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.050000
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419446347] [moveit_ros.fix_start_state_collision]: Param 'chomp.max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419453975] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Optimal Parameterization'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419457022] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Resolve constraint frames to robot links'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419477006] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419480395] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419483951] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.419487092] [moveit.ros_planning.planning_pipeline]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.471135731] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Added FollowJointTrajectory controller for arm_0_joint_trajectory_controller
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.471257691] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.471272738] [moveit.plugins.moveit_simple_controller_manager]: Returned 1 controllers in list
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.471638404] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.471650609] [move_group.move_group]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.501453155] [move_group.move_group]: 
[move_group-2] 
[move_group-2] ********************************************************
[move_group-2] * MoveGroup using: 
[move_group-2] *     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
[move_group-2] *     - ClearOctomapService
[move_group-2] *     - CartesianPathService
[move_group-2] *     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
[move_group-2] *     - GetPlanningSceneService
[move_group-2] *     - KinematicsService
[move_group-2] *     - MoveAction
[move_group-2] *     - MotionPlanService
[move_group-2] *     - QueryPlannersService
[move_group-2] *     - StateValidationService
[move_group-2] ********************************************************
[move_group-2] 
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.501560957] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[move_group-2] [INFO] [1725636336.501577969] [moveit_move_group_capabilities_base.move_group_context]: MoveGroup context initialization complete
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
[move_group-2] Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[move_group-2] 
[move_group-2] You can start planning now!
[move_group-2] 
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-4]: process has died [pid 7242, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args -r __ns:=/a200_0000 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_h4wk33np --params-file /home/aalmrad/demos/clearpath_kinova/clearpath_ws/install/clearpath_moveit_config/share/clearpath_moveit_config/config/ros2_controllers.yaml'].
[spawner-5] [WARN] [1725636337.015198372] [a200_0000.spawner_arm_0_joint_trajectory_controller]: Controller already loaded, skipping load_controller
[spawner-5] [ERROR] [1725636337.020843110] [a200_0000.spawner_arm_0_joint_trajectory_controller]: Failed to configure controller
[ERROR] [spawner-5]: process has died [pid 7244, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/controller_manager/spawner arm_0_joint_trajectory_controller --ros-args -r __ns:=/a200_0000'].
[rviz2-3] [ERROR] [1725636339.288740847] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Action server: /recognize_objects not available
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636339.319341929] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: MoveGroup namespace changed: /a200_0000 -> . Reloading params.
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636339.477819060] [moveit_rdf_loader.rdf_loader]: Loaded robot model in 0.0957596 seconds
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636339.477875291] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Loading robot model 'a200-0000'...
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636339.477890644] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[rviz2-3] [WARN] [1725636339.600401560] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Link user_bay_cover_link has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rviz2-3] [WARN] [1725636339.600563965] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Link front_bumper_link has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rviz2-3] [WARN] [1725636339.600799259] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Link top_chassis_link has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[rviz2-3] [WARN] [1725636339.601223701] [moveit_robot_model.robot_model]: Could not identify parent group for end-effector 'end_effector'
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636339.911022197] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Starting planning scene monitor
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636339.912942075] [moveit_ros.planning_scene_monitor.planning_scene_monitor]: Listening to '/a200_0000/monitored_planning_scene'
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636340.157332336] [a200_0000.interactive_marker_display_105151510163328]: Connected on namespace: /rviz_moveit_motion_planning_display/robot_interaction_interactive_marker_topic
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636340.176286084] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: group Gen3
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636340.176313722] [moveit_ros_visualization.motion_planning_frame]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'Gen3' in namespace ''
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636340.189929473] [a200_0000.interactive_marker_display_105151510163328]: Sending request for interactive markers
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636340.222444386] [a200_0000.interactive_marker_display_105151510163328]: Service response received for initialization
[rviz2-3] [INFO] [1725636400.194675624] [move_group_interface]: Ready to take commands for planning group Gen3.


If you need more information, please do not hesitate to let me know. Thanks in advance for your help
